# ORA-12514 for Oracle Devsuite 10g and Oracle DB 11g on the same host

Tags: oracle, installation

I have oracle devsuite 10g (forms, reports, etc...) on the same host as Oracle database 11g... Devsuite was installed prior to Oracle DB 11g.

When I go in Oracle DB 11g and launch `sqlplus sys as sysdba`, it works fine.

When I go to `DevsuiteHome/bin` and launch its version of sqlplus, it does not. The descriptor I supply here is `orcl`

The two products have their `tnsnames.ora` file. I made sure that both use the same values as `orcl`, hence, we have for both :

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

But, it does not work. When I try to connect in Oracle forms or using DevsuiteHOme/bin sqlplus, I get the error :

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the result of the command `lsnrctl status`?

Comment: @Marco Sorry. I just saw this comment. Never mind this question. I was trying to help someone. I should have not care I guess. They change their configuration so it'd be irrelevant to continue. Anyways, `lsnrctl status` was ok. It showed `command successfully` executed and also it printed the definitions of ORCL and as set in tnsnames.ora